# Format number with different separator of Excel using open XML

Tags: c#, excel, format, openxml

My excel and my computer is being formating with thousands separator is "," and decimal separator is "." and I must keep this format.
How can I use open XML with C# to format CellValue (Type: Number) with thousands separator is "." and decimal separator is ","

Ex: cellValue = 3250.83
I used CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE") --> 3250,83 (equal 325083) --> Wrong
Expected Cell On Excel : 3.250,83

Comment: And what happens when you do that?  It's not clear though exactly what you're doing here - are you working with Excel from C#?  If Yes then how? - there are a number of way to write to Excel from .NET

Comment: I used Culture.GetCultureInfo("de-DE") to format value (3250.83) and write to excel , but I recieved cell value (3250,83) , this cell value equal 325083 --> Wrong.  I expected cell value (3.250,83)

Comment: By "cell value" do you mean the actual value, or how it appears in the cell (which could be affected by the cell format) ?  Also, how are you populating the cell?